# When to use an apostrophe when your last name ends with an s

Tags: grammatical-number, orthography, apostrophe, names

Shortly after my wedding day my wonderful mother-in-law sat me down to say that my new name Barnes was to be spelled (in Christmas Cards) Love from the Barnes'. She went on to explain that her German mother-in-law had the same talk with her regarding Christmas Cards. So, in keeping with family tradition I have always said with love from the Barnes'

Now they are both on the other side and I am gaining a wonderful daughter-in-law and plan to keep the tradition going. But I am curious if it's grammatically incorrect.

Thoughts??

Comment: I swear I recognise this story, but I can't find a duplicate. Maybe I'm just suffering from deja-vu all over again.

Comment: Totally incorrect. There are exceedingly few words that take an apostrophe to form the non-possessive plural (do's / ex's ...) and only some people accept those. Some **_companies_** retain an apostrophe (Lloyd's of London), referring back to ownership, whereas others have got rid (Waterstones). But families, no.

Comment: Love from the Barnses--it's not, after all, love from the Barnses' dog

Answer (score 1):

Why is it that [addressing holiday cards](http://www.kansascity.com/living/article46749025.html) is [such a controversial topic](http://www.slate.com/blogs/browbeat/2014/11/25/how_to_make_your_last_name_plural_on_holiday_cards_and_avoid_apostrophe.html)?

This is not a matter of grammar, but of style. It's your name and your card, and you don't need to follow anyone else's rules if you don't care to. Besides, matters of family tradition, and of pleasing in-laws, are not resolved with citations from the Internet.

---

In current English usage, apostrophes signify possessives, not pluralization. Usually, the plural of a name ending is *s* or *z* is signified by adding *-es*. The *AP Stylebook*, for example, asserts

> PROPER NAMES: Most ending in *es* or *z* add *es*: *Charleses, Joneses, Gonzalezes*.

Similarly, the *Chicago Manual of Style* states flatly

> Names of persons and other proper nons form the plural in the usual way, by adding *s* or *es*:
>
> > … flouting the Joneses
>
> Note that the apostrophe is never used to denote the plural of a personal name: "The Schumachers left for London on Friday" (*not* "The Schumacher's …")

Such examples assume, however, that you would *pronounce* the plural of *Jones* as *Joneses*, adding a syllable. Whether you write *Dickens' novels* or *Dickens's novels*, or *an herb garden* or *a herb garden*, depends on how it sounds in your head. In the same vein, I would say if you *pronounce* the plural of *Barnes* indistinguishably from singular *Barnes*, you have liberty to sign the card as *love from the Barnes*, nitpickers be damned. Alternatively, you can sidestep the issue and offer *love from the Barnes family*.